# Merging lists of lists retaining order with groovy

Tags: list, groovy

I have two long lists of lists:

```
first = [[A, 2, 4, 6], [B, 1, 3, 5]...]
second = [[A, 8, 10, 12], [B, 7, 9, 11]...]
```

That would like to merge into (order retained)

```
first = [[A, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], [B, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]...]
```

(I'll be doing this inside an each{} of 'second' like results from a function call, so I need to keep merging into 'first')
I think I'm looking for some kind of addition, plus flattening, but I can't quite get it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are 'A' and 'B' elements of the lists or just a notation for clarity? If elements, are they strings?

Comment: A and B are consistent elements of the list that could be used as keys, but eventually I need just the first instance of each one.

Comment: Yes they are strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
def merge(a, b) {
  tmp = b.collectEntries { [it.first(), it.tail()] }
  return a.collect { it + tmp[it.first()] }
}
```

It makes a temporary `Map` that is keyed by the first sub-entry of each entry in the second list, and then looks up the appropriate thing to append while iterating through the first list.

For example:

```
A = "A"
B = "B"
​first = [[A, 2, 4, 6], [B, 1, 3, 5]]
second = [[A, 8, 10, 12], [B, 7, 9, 11]]

println merge(first, second)
```

It could probably be made more robust to missing elements and such.

Answer (score 4):

If:

- the lists are always matched so that if there is one 'A' record in `first` there is one in `second`, and if there's a 'B' record in `first`, there's one in `second`, etc
- The lists are ordered in the same order

Then you can get away with:

```
[ first, second ].transpose()*.flatten()*.unique()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't know if I can guarantee the ordering condition, but I will consider this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this solution, though it is somewhat brittle (e.g. when keys do not align). Also, this modifies the 'first' list as a side-effect, which is a bit of a smell.

```
// modifies 'first' as a side-effect
def merge = { def first, def subSecond ->
    def subFirst = first.find { it[0] == subSecond[0] }
    if (subFirst) {
        subFirst.addAll( subSecond[1..subSecond.size()-1] )
    }
}

// tests 

def first = null
def results = null

first = [["A",2,4,6],["B",1,3,5]]
results = []
results.each { def subSecond -> merge(first,subSecond) }
assert [["A",2,4,6],["B",1,3,5]] == first

first = [["A",2,4,6],["B",1,3,5]]
results = [ ["A",8,10,12] ]
results.each { def subSecond -> merge(first,subSecond) }
assert [["A",2,4,6,8,10,12],["B",1,3,5]] == first

first = [["A",2,4,6],["B",1,3,5]]
results = [ ["A",8,10,12],["B",7,9,11]  ]
results.each { def subSecond -> merge(first,subSecond) }
assert [["A",2,4,6,8,10,12],["B",1,3,5,7,9,11]] == first
```